# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UserCars_aspnet_Users"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, guid

I am trying to insert data to UserCars table using ObjectDataSource Insert Method. 
the userId(FOREIGN KEY) I am trying to insert is GUID type.

The primary key is `UserId(uniqeidentifier)` in aspnet_users table which is part of Membrship schema.

`userId(guid) = JustCreateduser` so it means it should be the same values.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I believe I read about issues with guid keys on sql with asp.net. Can you convert it to integer keys?

Comment: Earth to Alex... did you fix the problem? Any update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if it really does exist:

```
SELECT * FROM aspnet_users WHERE UserIDGUID = @TheGuidBeingInserted
```

If you're having trouble getting info on what's actually happening, do a trace in SQL Profiler, capturing SQL statement completion, SP statement completion, RPC call completion, and RPC output parameter (just in case the GUID is coming back from a call).

That should give you some ideas to be able to proceed forward with solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have used another approach wich worked. But I will keep in mind your suggestions in future Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed that the guid does actually exist in the aspnet_users table prior to inserting it into the UserCars table?

Comment: I call this after registration and put other details as well, so It should be there. Problem resolved Thankyou!